# how to include angularjs library file in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/angular.min.js.map"):
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/test-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/test-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/test-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered /home/test-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /home/test-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /home/test-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /home/test-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (17.8ms)
```

application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular.min
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I know that `/assets/angular.min.js.map` is not equal to `/assets/angular.min.js`, so do you have the file `/assets/angular.min.js.map` in your project?

Comment: I dont have /assets/angular.min.js.map, but I included /assets/javascripts/angular.min.js

Comment: That's why the error is happening. The code in the file `/assets/angular.min.js` is internally accessing the file `/assets/angular.min.js.map`. In most cases, you should be okay ignoring it. But, if this error is not letting your rails app run, then you must include the file in your project. It's available in compressed file available for download from angularjs.org.

Comment: https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails

I think it's more than easy

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to include `Angular.js` [Library](https://angularjs.org/) in rails then it is best to use gem.

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
```

**[angularjs-rails](https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails)** wraps the Angular.js library for use in **Rails 3.1** and **above**. Assets will minify automatically during production.

in your **application.js** add this

```
//= require angular
```

If you desire to require (optional) Angular files, you may include them as well in your JavaScript manifest file (application.js). For example:

```
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
```

For your reference https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-integrate-angularjs-with-rails-4

of course, gem 'angularjs-rails'  is one of other possibility

Comment: got a 404 on that link you shared.